# ORM копирование laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Как в laravel скопировать найденую запись

```
$test = Test::find(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$copy = $test->replicate()`
https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_replicate

Answer (score 0):

Клонировать можно.

```
$copy = clone $test;
```

Но тут нужно учитывать возможную магию типа __clone, если описана.